# Difference in Premove Limits: Lichess vs. Chess.com

Tags: online-chess, lichess, chess.com

I've noticed a distinct difference in the premove system between Lichess and Chess.com. Lichess allows only one premove at a time, whereas Chess.com permits multiple premoves. What is the rationale behind this difference in design? Does it significantly affect the strategy or pace of online chess games?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is somewhat significant (chaining premoves can be useful in certain situations, such as promoting an unopposed passed pawn in the endgame), but even more significant is that chess.com takes a tenth of a second off for each move regardless of premoving. This increases the danger of being low on time as a player often cannot effect a checkmate with a handful of seconds remaining even if the position is otherwise completely trivial to win.  On lichess, such positions are often winnable regardless of clock situation due to premoving.